# Wrong Result Codeigniter Query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'am new in codeigniter and php. This is my models:

```
function getRelated($newsId, $catId){
    $this->db->select('a.id, a.category, a.title, a.photo, a.caption, a. summary, a.detail, a.page_views, b.cat_id');
    $this->db->from('news as a');
    $this->db->order_by("time", "desc");
    $this->db->join('news_categories as b', 'a.id = b.news_id');
    $this->db->where('a.id <>', $newsId);
    $this->db->where('b.cat_id', $catId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result();
}
```

this is my controller:

```
public function detail($id, $catId){
        $this->load->model('news_model');
        $data['list'] = $this->news_model->get($id);
        $data['related'] = $this->news_model->getRelated($id, $catId);

        $this->load->view('page_header');           
        $this->load->view('news_detail', $data);            
        $this->load->view('page_footer');
}
```

And this is the result of query in views:

> SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`category`, `a`.`title`, `a`.`photo`,
>   `a`.`caption`, `a`. `summary`, `a`.`detail`, `a`.`page_views`,
>   `b`.`cat_id` FROM `news` as `a` JOIN `news_categories` as `b` ON
>   `a`.`id` = `b`.`news_id` WHERE `a`.`id` <> '2' AND `b`.`cat_id` =
>   'title%20one%20test1' ORDER BY `time` DESC

As you see above (views), the result of cat_id is title..
Whats wrong with my code?

my view file (news_detail):

```
<h3>Related News</h3>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($related as $key => $value) {
    if (++$i > 3)
        break;
    ?>
    <div class="list">
        <a class="title" href="news/detail/<?= $value->id . "/" . $value->title ?>"><?= $value->title ?></a>
    </div>
<?php
}?>
```

The category of post is multiple choice. So, every post can have more than one category. What should i do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your SQL looks fine. I am confused as to what the issue is. Can you post the relevant section of your view named `news_detail.php`? thanks

Comment: It looks like your `$catId` is a string, not an integer. How is your route setup look like? So if you haven't setup any routes, de default should be `the_controller_name/detail/2/3`

Comment: Hi @MonkeyZeus and Iamzozo : I just updated my question. I forgot to tell you that every post can have more than one category. What shoud i do? Thanks

Comment: can you please tell me what is `$id` and `$cat_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing mistake here

```
<a class="title" href="news/detail/<?= $value->id . "/" . $value->title ?>"><?= $value->title ?></a>
```

When you defined any function like

```
public function detail($id, $catId){ }
```

then `$id` will be first segment after method name `detail` i.e. `$value->id` and `$catId` will be second segment after method name i.e. `$value->title`.

so add catID as a second segment in link as below
    `<a class="title" href="news/detail/<?= $value->id . "/" . $value->catID ?>"><?= $value->title ?></a>`

Comment: Change anchor tag in view file (news_detail): <a class="title" href="news/detail/<?= $value->id . "/" . $value->title ?>"><?= $value->title ?></a>

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code. Try this...!

```
function getRelated($newsId, $catId){
        $this->db->select('a.id, a.category, a.title, a.photo, a.caption, a. summary, a.detail, a.page_views, b.cat_id');
        $this->db->from('news as a');
        $this->db->order_by("time", "desc");
        $this->db->join('news_categories as b', 'a.id = b.news_id and a.id<>'.$newID.'and b.cat_id=$catID','inner');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        echo $this->db->last_query();
        return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change anchor tag in view file (news_detail).

Here you are sending title rather than category id

replace

`<a class="title" href="news/detail/<?= $value->id . "/" . $value->title?>"><?= $value->title ?></a>`

by

```
<a class="title" href="news/detail/<?= $value->id . "/" . $value->cat_id?>"><?= $value->title ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace view file (news_detail):

```
<h3>Related News</h3>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($related as $key => $value) {
    if (++$i > 3)
        break;
    ?>
    <div class="list">
        <a class="title" href="news/detail/<?= $value->id . "/" . $value->cat_id ?>"><?= $value->title ?></a>
    </div>
<?php
}?>
```